# Add logo to multiple input videos in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

Trying to add a logo (same logo) to multiple input streams (videos) in ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -i test_logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2[v]; [v][v][v]hstack=inputs=3[top]; [v][v][v]hstack=inputs=3[bottom]; [top][bottom]vstack=inputs=2" OUTPUT.mp4
```

This results in only the first call of [v] (top left video) having the logo, the others are blank (video without the logo).

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found a bug in FFmpeg...

Workaround:
Use `split` filter after `overlay` - split the video with the logo into 6 video streams, and stack the 6 streams:

`ffmpeg -i INPUT.mp4 -i test_logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2,split=outputs=6[v0][v1][v2][v3][v4][v5]; [v0][v1][v2]hstack=inputs=3[top]; [v3][v4][v5]hstack=inputs=3[bottom]; [top][bottom]vstack=inputs=2" OUTPUT.mp4`

Comment: This worked like a charm, many thanks!

Didn't expect to find a bug honestly (thought it was user error), is there anywhere I can report this?

Comment: There is a chance that this bug is already reported (or even fixed). You may use Google for finding how to open a new bug report (I never reported a bug for FFmpeg).

Comment: Ticket is https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9830. I've edited the title and provided a minimal command example.

Comment: Oh so it is a bug, my mistake. Also apologies since I'm new to ffmpeg and not familiar with the terms used for various variables and such, thank you for the edit.